# WSDL2Java tool error Apache CXF

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java

We get the following error when we use WSDL2Java tool to generate stubs. The webservice is up and running.

WSDLToJava Error: org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLRuntimeException: Fail to create wsd
l definition from : http://scheduler.heartbeatsoftware.com/scheduler/WebServices
/SampleSNMWebService?wsdl
Caused by : WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentExce
ption: InputSource must have a ByteStream or CharacterStream

If we donwload the wsdl and generate stubs from that wsdl, they are generated. But the java client using those stubs throws the same exception as above

Strangely when we deploy the same webservice on our LAN such a problem is not encountered stubs are generated sucessfully and the subsequent java client works well.

The webservice is created using apache cxf version 2.2.5 and hosted on tomcat 6

Any pointers would be appreciated

regards
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. Just need to modify the wsdl.java.bat to include proxy settings
-Dhttp.proxyHost= -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080